# Clear the kill ring in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editors

How does one clear the kill ring in emacs? I use browse-kill-ring.el but the buffer it provides is read-only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For me, `M-:` `(setq kill-ring nil)` works. See also [Internals of Kill Ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Internals-of-Kill-Ring.html#Internals-of-Kill-Ring) in the elisp manual.  Don't ask me about side effects and security aspects, though.

Invoking the garbage collection right away as in

```
(progn (setq kill-ring nil) (garbage-collect))
```

makes the conses less accessible, so this might give you some degree of security.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite practical. I don't know enough about the internals of emacs memory management but I would guess setting a variable to nil doesn't guarantee deleting the contents from memory. So naturally, my next question would be about the security implications of this but you beat me to it :-). Googling about this gives me surprisingly little info. Am I the only one editing "sensitive" files with emacs?

Comment: Maybe garbage collecting makes the list cells less accessible? See the modified answer.